# RTK Query & Typescript - Property `url` does not exist in `RequestInfo` when declaring `fetchFn` method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, fetch-api, rtk-query

I'm trying to migrate all my fetch logic to RTK Query, and I'm trying to use my custom `fetch` setting the `fetchFn` inside the `fetchBaseQuery` method. Right now I'm still working on it, but I get an error telling me `Property url does not exist in RequestInfo`:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiRepositoryApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: getApiBaseUrl('api'),
    fetchFn: async (input, init) => {
      const { url } = input; // <-- Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RequestInfo'.ts(2339)

      console.log({
        init,
        url: (input as any).url, // It displays the URL correctly
      });
      
      return { data: [] } as any; // Returning something while testing so it does not complain
    },
    ...
  }),
  ...
});
```

The `input` variable is of type `RequestInfo` as per RTK Query definition, and although I can see the `url` value in the `console.log`, it's telling me the property does not exist.

I understand it's a readonly property, but although I cannot modify it, I should be able at least to read its value, but somehow I cannot (Typescript and EsLint complain about it).

**Am I missing something? How should I access the URL coming in the `input` parameter, otherwise?**

My `package.json` dependencies regarding Typescript and EsLint are the following:

```
"react": "18.0.0",
"typescript": "5.3.3",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.57.0",
"eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys": "2.1.0",
"eslint": "8.34.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
"eslint-plugin-jest": "27.2.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-sort-destructure-keys": "1.5.0",
```

And this is some of my `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ESNext",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "esm": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Thank you!